# min&max value kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, max, aggregate, min

How to find the min and max value of selected cells in a kendo grid using jquery.

Like the user need to find the min & max of only selected cells.(If the number contain any special character, then the special character should be neglected)

[Selected cells to find the minimum and maximum value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rAIJ.png)

Comment: No mean to be rude but have you tried anything to achieve that or you expect to get an easy answer with the job done for you like your last question ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - what's sad is that all I did was copy/paste my last answer and replace the `reduce` method with the `Math.min` and `Math.max` methods. It's not like there was a big difference between questions, really just the end operation changed.

Comment: @David exactly. Your last answer was good enough to evolve and resolve this question, but I dont think OP want to "waste its time" learning how to do it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `selectable.mode` property to `multiple, cell`.
2. In the `change` event, get the selected cells by calling `this.select()`
3. Get just the values of the selected cells by calling `Object.values`
4. Filter the values to only return values that are `<td />` elements
5. Map the filtered values to only return the converted inner text of the element

Once you have the values, you would get the min/max by using the `Math.max` and `Math.min` methods.

Example:

```js
change: function() {
  var selectedCells = Object.values(this.select())
    .filter(function(value) {
      return value && value.nodeName && value.nodeName == 'TD';
    })
    .map(function(td) {
      return Number(td.innerText);
    });
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, selectedCells);
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, selectedCells);
  console.log(`Min: ${min}. Max: ${max}`);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/AJaQiQAQ